# Simple MySQL Duplicate Removal

Tags: mysql, sql, select, primary-key, distinct

I'm attempting to just get rows from my database.  However, for some reason, some rows return as duplicates even though there is a DISTINCT command on the IDPosts portion.  The problem is the AND/OR statement for checking for post expiration date.  Any ideas would be appreciated to get this down to zero duplicates.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT IDPosts, 
      profile_picture,
      body, 
      post_date, 
      expires, 
      filename, 
      username 
FROM Posts, Users 
WHERE Posts.IDUser = Users.IDUser AND expires IS NULL OR expires >= NOW() 
ORDER BY `Posts`.`post_date` DESC
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` removes duplicates.  Please post results to show what is happening.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the WHERE clause. It sounds like you believe the DISTINCT only affects IDPosts, but it applies to all returned columns. If you want it to apply only to IDPosts, you should make some choice of which rows to return when you have the same IDPosts column but different information in the other columns. For example, you can GROUP BY IDPosts, and use an aggregate function on each group for each of the other columns.

Comment: Should `AND expires IS NULL OR expires >= NOW()` be `AND (expires IS NULL OR expires >= NOW())` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is related to your problem, but you should probably have parentheses around the conditions on `expires` in the `where` clause.  The logic is probably not doing what you intend.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDPosts, profile_picture, body, post_date, expires,
      filename, username
FROM Posts JOIN
     Users 
     ON Posts.IDUser = Users.IDUser
WHERE 
      (expires IS NULL OR expires >= NOW() )
ORDER BY `Posts`.`post_date` DESC;
```

Now that I also fixed the join syntax to use proper explicit joins.

Comment: Thank you!!  I did not know the parenthesis was most needed.